# Combination without repetition of next item

Tags: prolog

I have two list (size & color), i'm looking to build a single list without the repetition of one attribute between each element

I have a predicate:

```
list_pairs(List1, List2, Pairs) :-
    findall((X,Y), (member(X, List1), member(Y, List2)), Pairs).
```

who can help me generate all available combination:

```
list_pairs([red,blue,white,yellow],[small,big],T).
T = [(red,small), (red,big), (blue,small), (blue,big), (white,small), (white,big), (yellow,small), (yellow,big)]
```

But i don't know where i should head if i want alternate these parameters like :

```
T = [(yellow,big), (red,small), (blue,big), (white,small),(red,big),(yellow,small), (white,big), (blue, small)]
```

I should avoid repetition of parameters like two red next to each other or two small next to each other too.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I think you have to write your own predicate and state what pattern you want to obtain, instead of using `findall/3`.

Comment: Where does `(yellow, black)` come from?

Comment: Sorry typo, it's (yellow,big)

Comment: I don't see how Prolog is supposed to know that you want the order `yellow,red,blue,white / red,yellow,white,blue` from a list in order `[red,blue,white,yellow]` unless you have omitted some important information. I can understand why you want to alternate `small` and `big`.